# How to query count of all tags on a Stack Exchange site in a single request

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I'm experimenting with some machine learning techniques.
In this case [PSO-KMean](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4651388) for clustering.

I thought I might test it out by hitting the Stack Exchange API up
to grab a list of tags and a count of each tag,
then convert that into a array of floats representing each sites position in "tag-space"

I am using [Py-Stack-Exchange](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange)

```
from stackauth import StackAuth
import stackexchange 

site_data = {}
n_sites= 20
for site_auth in StackAuth().sites()[3:n_sites+3]: #Skip big 3
    site=site_auth.get_site()
    site_tags = {}
    for tag in site.all_tags():
        site_tags[(tag.name)]=tag.count
    site_data[site.domain] = site_tags
```

Now this must have [gone over the 10,000 requests limit](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) after I messed around with it a few times  because
I got  `StackExchangeError: 502 [throttle_violation]: too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 81719 seconds`

So I guess it is making a request for each and every tag on the site to get its count.
This is no good for anyone,
it is slower for me, and more work on the Stack Exchange Infrastructure.
I feel like there must be a way to get the information in 1 hit per site,
but am not familiar enough with the API to work it out.

Comment: what does #skip big 3 in your code mean?

Comment: It means to skip superuser, stack overflow and server fault. They (in particular Stackoverflow) are just to big.  This code might actually be skipping Meta SE, SO and SU, but not SF but that i OK, cos Meta is huge, bigger than SF i would guess

Comment: so did you figure out a solution for this? If so, please post it. It will be useful for others here!

Comment: No, I have not. otherwise I would have.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pull all the tags with only 1 API call. On Stack Overflow, alone, there are [38,484](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&filter=!9YdnSNNB1&site=stackoverflow&run=true) tags as of this answer. At 100 tags per page, that means you have to make 385 separate calls.

An alternative to the API for this problem, may be to utilize the Data Explorer. Without more details, I can point you at a very [simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229727) that pulls all tag information for Stack Overflow:

```
select * from tags
```

This information is updated on a weekly basis, so it is not live data.

Finally, you could use the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) for off line analysis. This is a large archive that Stack Exchange makes available on a quarterly basis (approximately). Fortunately, the newest dump is from September 2014, so it is fairly up to date.

Comment: if you want to programmatically pull the tags, that is carry out `select * from tags`, how would you achieve that? That will help SO to refine his code..I guess users don't have access to Stack Overflow database

Comment: You don't. Utilize the data dump and store the information in your own database at that point.

Comment: I guess this involves downloading the zip files and doing analysis on it. But I usually prefer direct API calls to pull information and persist at my end. May be that is not possible here as the SO mentions he hits StackExchange server with too many calls...